# Python: skip lines of programming based on a condition in a while loop?

Tags: python

The program I have is rather complicated so I've just decided to take this portion.
Basically, this code is supposed to loop through a series of lines and stop once `TIME` has reached 4800; however, if `quepax` has reached 15 in a loop, it will evaluate `R`. If the loop is not yet broken by `TIME>=4800`, subsequent loops will not get new values of `R` (since `quepax` will always be more than 15 from there) while still going through the rest of the lines. Below is an attempt to do such a program. It sort of works, but is it possible to make a simpler code without repeating content?

```
    while True:
            i+=1
            pax[i]=random.randint(1,5)
            TOTALPAX+=pax[i]
            TIME+=between[i]
            queue+=pax[i]
            if quepax>15:
                R=i-1
                while True:
                    i+=1
                    pax[i]=random.randint(1,5)
                    TOTALPAX+=pax[i]
                    TIME+=between[i]
                    queue+=pax[i]
                    if TIME>=4800:
                        break
            if TIME>=4800:
                break
```

Comment: I would probably not put this in nested loops.

Comment: Yes, so I'm wondering if I can do this without a nested loop.

Comment: To "skip lines given a condition", you'd do `if not "condition": `. Can you be more clear about your goal? Write down exactly what you want, in a way that does not need any more explanations. From there to code, it should be only a small step left.

Comment: "Not sure if it works yet." You mean you haven't tried this actual program and see what happens?

Comment: One classic way to avoid a double break is to put the whole code in a function, and `return` and instead of `break`.

Comment: I will probably try that. I heard that `return` can act as a control flow. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7129285/why-would-you-use-the-return-statement-in-python

Comment: Well I realized that I want to simply avoid repeating the lines, and the double break is not so important. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find this solution which eliminates the repeated parts, but it still looks rather unconventional. Is there an alternative to this?

```
    run=0
    while True:
            i+=1
            pax[i]=random.randint(1,5)
            TOTALPAX+=pax[i]
            TIME+=between[i]
            queue+=pax[i]
            if quepax>15 and run=0:
                R=i-1
                run=1
            if TIME>=4800:
            break
```

Comment: If you try to do a thing at most once in a loop, it's not unconventional to use a flag for this. You should rename `run` to something more meaningful and use boolean values. For example: `setR = True; ... if quepax > 15 and setR: R=i-1; setR=False`

Comment: Thanks. I was just trying to think of something quick on the spot, so apologies for that. But I think that solved my problem.

Comment: It indeed looks a bit odd for typical Python code with all that indexing but it is hard to suggest anything different with all those ”holes”. `quepax` is never changed in the shown code so it is either always >15 or never. `queue` and `TOTALPAX` are incremented in sync and not used in that loop so you could add up in a temporary variable and add the result to both after the loop. Instead of `while` and incrementing `i` manually a `for` loop would be the natural choice.